# Change the time zone in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

my project is hosted on shared server and i want to change
 the timezone to Asia/Kolkata.
i have tried setting timezone using htaccess file but failed.

Comment: what you can and cant change varies from provider to provider, you may be able to do it in php.ini, but i would just ask them first.

Comment: Does your application expect the server to be on GMT, and you want to know how to use CodeIgniter to properly display the time zone based on that? Or do you want to set it so that PHP itself sees Asia/Kolkata time when it queries the server?

Comment: @robert i want php date function to use that setting where ever i have used date function

Comment: @Dagon i don't have access to php.ini file :(

Comment: I assume you've already tried putting php_value date.timezone "Asia/Kolkata" in your .htaccess file?

Comment: buy a vps or move to host in your desired timezone.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With CodeIgniter, the best place to set the timezone is inside the main `index.php` file.  It's at the same level in your project structure as the `system/` and `application/` folders.

Just add the following as the first line of code in the file after the opening `<?php` tag:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

That should do it for all your PHP code.

Don't forget that if you're using a database, the timezone for the database will probably be different as well.  If you're using MySQL, you'll want to do a `SET time_zone = "+05:30"` query as soon as you open a database connection.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

in your index.php file.  You don't need to have access to your php.ini file.

Comment: i don't have access to php.ini file

Comment: You can run this from your scriptFile.php file itself. Not from php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Another good practice is to put it in the CI_Controller class, right in the __construct function:

```
public function __construct() {
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Asia/Kolkata' );
    self::$instance =& $this;
    // the rest of the code...
```

Comment: This is actually the only `correct` way to do it even though everything mentioned in other answer does work. The protocol is NOT TO change codeigniter's files for any reason. Do whatever changes you need in your own `application/` controllers. Good job

Answer (score 1):

Do it This Way

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'ci',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE,
'date_default_timezone_set' => 'Asia/Kolkata'
);
```

Comment: i ve used timestamp in my table ( mysql) is it effect by using this setting?      i tried but i didnt see any change.... my server is in new zealand but i need to set time for uk. for any inserted record in tables, timestamp set to time in new zealand... how to change timestamp to uk timezone.

Comment: use  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); in top of config.php .

Comment: but it does not effect for timestamp fields in mysql tables. just it works with date() not timestamp. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah thanks, i try in my controller like this :

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
 * Description of Testime
 * @class Testing
 */

class Testing extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    }

    public function index(){
        echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

And works :)

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code in the index.php file of the your Codeigniter project

```
 datedefaulttimezoneset(‘Asia/Kolkata’);
```

Or You can also change using the php.ini file.

Also for more help visit http://www.tutorial-hub.com/top-interview-questions-and-answers-codeigniter-framework/

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
```

Placing this in config.php. It works!

Comment: Can you provide some comments on why this is (supposed to be) working? Just pasting some code is not really helpful.