# How to set timezone in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone

Which is better way to set timezone in Codeigniter?
I've tried this in index.php

`date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");`

Is it possible?

Comment: It has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309536/how-to-set-time-zone-in-code-igniter/31309903#31309903

Answer (score 8):

Two options for adding timezone in codeigniter. I tried with both and both is working fine for whole project.

- add it in your main index.php file.
- place it in your config file like this(After defined('BASEPATH') Line).

  ```
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
  ```

Comment: You do not need to have it in your index.php file works fine just in the config.php file

Comment: can you post an example