# How to change cPanel datetime zone?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, hosting, cpanel

How to change cPanel date.time zone?

My `php.ini` is like this:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 64M;
max_execution_time = 36000;
upload_max_filesize = 999M;
safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.auto_start = Off;
session.use_only_cookies = On;
session.use_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.cookie_httponly = On;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600;
allow_url_fopen = on;
date.timezone = "US/Central";
display_errors = 1;
error_reporting = E_ALL;
```

And `phpinfo()` shows like this:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309536/how-to-set-time-zone-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Using htaccess file we can able to change timezone

## Adjust default time zone

SetEnv TZ America/Washington

Answer (score 0):

if u want to use another timezone in `php` script you can use

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: i just copied this code into php.ini but its not working??

Comment: why do you want to change cpanel time zone. When u can set timezone to another timezone  in `php` for eg. if your server timezone is `America/New_York` then using above instruction you can change timezone to` Europe/London`

Comment: @RAHEEZPC You need to copy this code in your php file not in .ini

Answer (score 0):

@RAHEEZ PC, you have to restart your apache service after making change in php.ini file. Restarting the server or apache service is must to have your changes in effect.

Or

You can set runtime timezone, like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Write above mentioned line in your index.php file or some master file, because it includes all other files of your project.
I have `America/Los_Angeles` because it will set USA central time.

Comment: i am working in c-panel so i don't know how to restart it. If you give me the path to restart. It will be helpful to me

Comment: @RAHEEZPC, I would still recommend you to take 2nd approach, defining `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` in your master file.

Comment: If you will set timezone in php.ini file then it will be applicable to apache's timezone and so that timezone will be applicable to all other projects you will upload, so better to set project level timezones rather than setting up server level timezone.

Comment: I also read that `Be assured, though, that your restart DOES affect everyone else on your shared server!` so better not to do this, but set using php function.

Answer (score 0):

if you have root access, to set the correct time zone, use the following procedure:

```
Log in to your WHM as root.
Go to "Server Configuration" Section.
Click on "Server Time".
Select the appropriate timezone.
Click on the "Change TimeZone" button.
```

If the time is still shown incorrectly, you can synchronize the server time with a time server by clicking on "Sync Time with Time Server".

Answer (score 0):

`config/config.php` before `base_url` you should write

> date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');