# Students can start exam even when the exam date has not been reached

Tags: php, codeigniter

It turns out that students can actually start an exam even when the exam date is still to the future.
Normally, when a student clicks on the 'start exam' button when it's not time, there is usually a warning message but for some reason, it doesn't work again.

Students should be restricted from being able to start an exam when the date of the exam has not been reached

View

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info questions" data-recordid="<?php echo $exam->id; ?>"  data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Please wait..."><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> <?php echo $this->lang->line('start') . " " . $this->lang->line('exam') ?></button>
```

Teacher Controller

```
  public function add() {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('exam', $this->lang->line('exam'), 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('attempt', $this->lang->line('attempt'), 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('exam_from', $this->lang->line('exam') . " " . $this->lang->line('from'), 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('exam_to', $this->lang->line('exam') . " " . $this->lang->line('to'), 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('duration', $this->lang->line('duration'), 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', $this->lang->line('description'), 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passing_percentage', $this->lang->line('percentage'), 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

            $msg = array(
                'exam' => form_error('exam'),
                'attempt' => form_error('attempt'),
                'exam_from' => form_error('exam_from'),
                'duration' => form_error('duration'),
                'exam_to' => form_error('exam_to'),
                'description' => form_error('description'),
                'passing_percentage' => form_error('passing_percentage'),
            );

            $array = array('status' => 0, 'error' => $msg, 'message' => '');
        } else {
            $is_active = 0;
            $publish_result = 0;
            if (isset($_POST['is_active'])) {
                $is_active = 1;
            }
            if (isset($_POST['publish_result'])) {
                $publish_result = 1;
            }
            $idd = $this->session->userdata('admin');
            $insert_data = array(
                'exam' => $this->input->post('exam'),
                'attempt' => $this->input->post('attempt'),
                'exam_from' => date('Y-m-d', $this->customlib->datetostrtotime($this->input->post('exam_from'))),
                'exam_to' => date('Y-m-d', $this->customlib->datetostrtotime($this->input->post('exam_to'))),
                'duration' => $this->input->post('duration'),
                'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                'session_id' => $this->setting_model->getCurrentSession(),
                'is_active' => $is_active,
                'publish_result' => $publish_result,
                'passing_percentage' => $this->input->post('passing_percentage'),
                'teacher_id'     => $idd['id'],
            );
            $id = $this->input->post('recordid');
            if ($id != 0) {
                $insert_data['id'] = $id;
            }

            $this->onlineexam_model->add($insert_data);

            $array = array('status' => 1, 'error' => '', 'message' => $this->lang->line('success_message'));
        }

        echo json_encode($array);
    }
```

user controller

```
 public function startexam____($id) {
        $data = array();
        $this->session->set_userdata('top_menu', 'Hostel');
        $this->session->set_userdata('sub_menu', 'hostel/index');
        $questionOpt = $this->customlib->getQuesOption();
        $data['questionOpt'] = $questionOpt;
        $onlineexam_question = $this->onlineexam_model->getExamQuestions($id);
        $data['examquestion'] = $onlineexam_question;
        $this->load->view('layout/student/header');
        $this->load->view('user/onlineexam/startexam', $data);
        $this->load->view('layout/student/footer');
    }

 public function getExamForm() {
        $data = array();
        $question_status = 0;
        $recordid = $this->input->post('recordid');
        $exam = $this->onlineexam_model->get($recordid);

        $data['questions'] = $this->onlineexam_model->getExamQuestions($recordid);
        $student_current_class = $this->customlib->getStudentCurrentClsSection();
        $student_session_id = $student_current_class->student_session_id;
        $onlineexam_student = $this->onlineexam_model->examstudentsID($student_session_id, $exam->id);
        $data['onlineexam_student_id'] = $onlineexam_student;
        $getStudentAttemts = $this->onlineexam_model->getStudentAttemts($onlineexam_student->id);

        $data['question_status'] = 0;

        if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) >= strtotime(date($exam->exam_to . ' 23:59:59'))) {

            $question_status = 1;
            $data['question_status'] = 1;
        } else if ($exam->attempt > $getStudentAttemts) {
            $this->onlineexam_model->addStudentAttemts(array('onlineexam_student_id' => $onlineexam_student->id));
        } else {
            $question_status = 1;
            $data['question_status'] = 1;
        }

        $questionOpt = $this->customlib->getQuesOption();
        $data['questionOpt'] = $questionOpt;
        $pag_content = $this->load->view('user/onlineexam/_searchQuestionByExamID', $data, true);
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 0, 'exam' => $exam, 'page' => $pag_content, 'question_status' => $question_status));
    }
```

Comment: Where in your code do you select the available exams?

Comment: @RoAchterberg do you mean the getExamForm() function?

Comment: Please show us `$exam->exam_to`'s value before the `strtotime()` comparison.

Comment: could it be just a timezone issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309536/how-to-set-time-zone-in-codeigniter

Comment: @RoAchterberg okay, you lost me there. How do I find the value?

Comment: @Vickel no luck there

Comment: ok so where in your code, does it decide to show the "warning message". From what you have supplied so far in getexamform() the IF Block below the line $data['question_status'] = 0; would be were I'd start poking around

Comment: In this line `if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) >= strtotime(date($exam->exam_to . ' 23:59:59'))) {`, what is `$exam->exam_to` set to? Use `var_dump()` to find out.