# MySQL timestamp showing in wrong timezone

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, timestamp, timezone

I am saving a timestamp in my MySQL database with the creation time of a record. When fetching it using CodeIgniter (a PHP framework) it shows in UTC while my timezone is UTC+2. I think that timestamps are stored always in UTC, that's ok, but I don't know how to display it in UTC+2. Same CodeIgniter application in local shows in UTC+2, probably because my computer is in UTC+2 while my server is in UTC.

Is it possible to change a timestamp to another timezone using PHP or a CodeIgniter function, without changing the timezone of either my MySQL server or the web server itself? (I am using a shared hosting, that's why changing the timezone is probably not possible).

Thank you!

Comment: [date helper functions](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html?highlight=timezone#available-functions)

Comment: @Vickel Could you further explain? `now` is to get the current timestamp which is not the case (I am reading it from a database). And `timezone_select` is to create forms, which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the MySQL time zone for your session with something like

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/Berlin';
```

If you give this command immediately after you make your MySql connection each time, you'll always see your TIMESTAMP values rendered in your local time. This uses the so-called zoneinfo database, which is kept current with temporopolitical changes.

The list of zone names is [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

You don't have to change MySQL's global time zone setting to do this.

Comment: Is there a solution using PHP instead of changing the database session timezone?

Comment: By the way, where should I place `SET time_zone = 'Europe/Berlin';` in my CodeIgniter app?

Comment: See this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309536/how-to-set-time-zone-in-codeigniter  And if you choose to do all your timezone processing in php change the datatypes in your tables from TIMESTAMP to DATETIME; you don't want both MySQL and php doing timezone stuff.